# popup at different position where the cursor clicks css

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```
               <div class="checkbox">
                    <input id="230am" type="checkbox" onclick="openPopup()"> <label for="230am"></label>

                    <div id="popupBk">
                        <div id="title">Reminder</div>
                        <div id="timeSelect">
                            Start time: <input id="field1" /><br /><br />
                            End time: <input id="field2" /><br /><br />
                        </div>

                        <button onclick="processTime('field1','field2')" name="submit" id="submitButton"/>Create</button>
                        <div id="close_popup" title="Close this menu" onclick="closePopup()">
                            <p>X</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                     <input id="3am" type="checkbox"> <label for="3am"></label>

                <div id="popupBk">
                        <div id="title">Reminder</div>
                        <div id="timeSelect">
                            Start time: <input id="field1" /><br /><br />
                            End time: <input id="field2" /><br /><br />
                        </div>

                        <button onclick="processTime('field1','field2')" name="submit" id="submitButton"/>Create</button>
                        <div id="close_popup" title="Close this menu" onclick="closePopup()">
                            <p>X</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Below are my css:

```
       #popupBk{
         position: absolute;
         width: 25%;
         height: 20%;
         border: 2px solid grey;
         border-radius: 2px;
         background-color: white;
         margin-left: 3%;
         box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px;
         display: none;
         }
```

So I am trying to do a calendar app. I put two popup in two checkboxes just want to do that different popup will display under each checkbox once I click. Any ideas how to do this?

i think there is a way to make each class name differently and then create its own css, but if that it might needs a huge work. Or is there any other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:checked` state of checkboxes in CSS, coupled with the general sibling selector (`~`) to do this.

Read about sibling selectors here: https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Here's a live example:

```css
.wrapper {
  float: left;
}

.hidden {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" id="box1" /> <label for="box1">Show Box 1</label>

  <div class="hidden">Box 1</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" id="box2" /> <label for="box2">Show Box 2</label>

  <div class="hidden">Box 2</div>
</div>
```